# Call object attribute with numpy element - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Any way to call an object with numpy element?

Getting bellow error due to the fact it is not name of the variable I set for the certain object but I set that name in an array with which I want to call it with if that makes sense.

AttributeError: 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'beverage'

```
choice_array = np.array([
 "item0",
 "item1",
 "item2",
 "item3",
 "item4",
], dtype=str)

item1 = test_class("name1", 50, "50p")
item2 = test_class("name2", 50, "50p")
item3 = test_class("name3", 50, "50p")

def payment_coins(item_selection):
  x = choice_array[item_selection]
  print(x)
  print("You have selected: ", x.beverage, "\n")
  cost_item = str(input("Please enter " + x.cost_str + " -> "))
```

It will print the correct "itemX" from the array but the it won't set the object variable x.beverage etc to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `choice_array` contains strings `"item0"`, etc. When you `print(x)` you're just printing that string. `x.beverage` can't work because `x` is a string.

Comment: Thanks. Any way around it or I have to re-think it all?

Comment: Have you seen what I just posted as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store your self-defined objects in the numpy array, you will need to instantiate the objects first, then populate the array. In your example, the numpy array contains strings that happen to be the same as the `test_class` objects, but apart from that there's no relationship and they have no attributes.

```
item0 = test_class("name1", 50, "50p")
item1 = test_class("name2", 50, "50p")
item2 = test_class("name3", 50, "50p")

choice_array = np.array([
 item0,
 item1,
 item2,
])

def payment_coins(item_selection):
  x = choice_array[item_selection]
  print(x)
  print("You have selected: ", x.beverage, "\n")
  cost_item = str(input("Please enter " + x.cost_str + " -> "))
```